# Find the position of a circle tangent to two other circles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Say there are 3 circles, A, centered at point a, B centered at point b, and C, centered at point c. Each has a known radius independent of the others, Ar, Br, and Cr. The positions of a and b are known, but the position of c isn't.

The distance between a and b will always be between (Ar + Br) and (Ar + Br + (2 * Cr)).

I'm looking for an algorithm to find the position of c so that circles A and C are tangent, and circles B and C are tangent. There ought to be two solutions unless a and b are at their maximum allowed distance, in which case there would only be one.

[image: pseudo-code algorithm]

Thank you, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just need that the distance between the centre of $C$ and the centre of $A$ is $r_A+r_C$, while the distance between the centre of $C$ and the centre of $B$ is $r_B+r_C$, hence you just need to intersect two circles to find the position(s) of $C$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  How do I find that intersection point mathematically?

Comment: @RichardEllwood: you just need to solve the system given by $(x-x_A)^2+(y-y_A)^2=(r_A+r_C)^2$ and $(x-x_B)^2+(y-y_B)^2=(r_B+r_C)^2$ where $(x_A,y_A)$ and $(x_B,y_B)$ are the coordinates of the centres of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: +1 although as well as the circle centred at A radius $r_A+r_C$ and the circle centred at B radius $r_B+r_C$, it may also be worth drawing the circle centred at A radius $|r_A-r_C|$ and the circle centred at B radius $|r_B-r_C|$ and looking for more intersections.